# Python one liner with if in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm having a problem .

How can I write below one liner using function?

```
def onlyPairs(string):
    for x in string:
        if int(x)%2:
            return False
    return True

print [string for string in map(str, myList) if onlyPairs(string) ]
```

I've been on it for hours, I feel I'm getting close but I can't see the solution involving only one line.

I'm trying to have a list of numbers with each figure of the number that is even.

For example if mylist is [1200,3520,2002,2006,1230] then the line should produce a new list with only [2002,2006] in it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create a list of strings (of 1 character length) of even numbers? In one line?

Comment: Why do you care how big a function is? It'll be one line regardless when you call it. Saving 4 lines to create a less readable function is hardly worth it.

Comment: I know and I'm totally aware of this, but the point is that I want to train doing one liners ,even if it's less readable.
Our professor just loves one liners, and did last year exam with only one liners.
So I wanna be prepared .

Comment: Get a new professor. Seventh line of the Zen of Python: "Readability counts."

Comment: I agree that readability counts (and the professor should point this out, too), but as a programming excercise, one-lines make sense, IMHO, as they require learning lots of builtins and such (like `all` in this case) and promote a functional programming style.

Answer (score 4):

use sets:

```
myList = [1200, 3520, 2002, 2006, 1230]
print [num for num in myList if not set(str(num)) - set('02468')]
```

Comment: Alternatively: `if not str(num).translate(None, '02468')`

Answer (score 2):

Use a generator expression with [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
[item for item in myList if all(not int(x)%2 for x in str(item))]
```

But it seems that you want to check if all digits of a number are even. Which in that case converting the number to string is not a good idea. Instead you can use following function, which works with integers:

```
def check_all_even(num):
  while num:
    n = num % 10
    num = num / 10
    if n % 2:
      return False
  return True
```

The filter your list with it:

```
filter(check_all_even, myList)
```

Demo:

```
lst = [1200, 3520, 2002, 2006, 1230]
print filter(check_all_even, lst) # In python 3.x print(list(filter(check_all_even, lst))) 
[2002, 2006]
```

Comment: Clearly you have understood the problem at hand (both first and second degrees), and your answer readily addresses that problem. That said, *explaining* the code in your answer would go a long way towards helping the questioner (and further readers) I believe. Also, upvotes would come.

Comment: Thanks a lot .
The all( ) function helped me a lot, I was trying to do something close to it , but didn't manage to.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yes, the `not` should be inside the `all()` function, I think at first I thought all the digits should be odd. Thanks for attention.

Comment: It didn't do "all odd", either. It did "not all odd". Now it's "all not odd", and alternatively you could use "not any odd" (which should be slightly faster, since the `not` is only applied once per number, not once per digit).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
myList = [1200, 3520, 2002, 2006, 1230]
print map(str, filter(lambda x: all([int(d) % 2 == 0 for d in str(x)]), myList))
```

Comment: @tobias_k Because this answer was posted before the OP edited

Comment: Ah, my bad. But now, this will produce a generator with Python 3. Might be better to use a list comprehension instead of map.